# How to reset navigationviewcontroller ios swift

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I am having app with Slider where I have provided drop down to switch between users. As soon as app user switch to other user I want to reset entire navigation flow and start it from 1st screen.

For e.g

**Screen A -> Screen B -> Screen C -> Screen D -> User opens slider and switch users -> Jump to Screen A (Remove other screen from navigation). We can consider gmail app example here, where we can switch between different accounts and gmail app redirect user to primary inbox.**

**EDIT :**

I am using library for Slider menu available on git.

https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift

```
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

       var window: UIWindow?
       var navigationController: UINavigationController?
       var storyboard: UIStoryboard?
       var leftViewController: LeftSidePanelViewController?
       // var uuid: String?

       func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
           if Utility.getUserStatus() == 0 {
               storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
               let mainViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

               leftViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftSidePanelViewController") as? LeftSidePanelViewController

               navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
               UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
               leftViewController!.mainViewController = navigationController

let slideMenuController = ExSlideMenuController(mainViewController:navigationController!, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController!)
               slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
               slideMenuController.delegate = mainViewController

self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 236.0, green: 238.0, blue: 241.0, alpha: 1.0)
               self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
               self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
               Utility.setUUID(UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString)
           } else {
               storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
               let mainViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
               leftViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftSidePanelViewController") as? LeftSidePanelViewController
               navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
               UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
               leftViewController!.mainViewController = navigationController

let slideMenuController = ExSlideMenuController(mainViewController:navigationController!, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController!)
               slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
               slideMenuController.delegate = mainViewController

self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 236.0, green: 238.0, blue: 241.0, alpha: 1.0)
               self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
               self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
           }
           return true
       }
    }
```

I have tried different solutions for this but nothing seems to be working.

```
var alreadyPushed = false
           //Check if the view was already pushed
           if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
               for viewController in viewControllers {
                   if let viewController = viewController as? HomeViewController {
                       self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true);
                       print(" Push Your Controller")
                       alreadyPushed = true
                       break
                   }
               }
           }

           if alreadyPushed == false {
               print("Pushing...")
               let YourControllerObject = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
               self.navigationController?.presentViewController(YourControllerObject, animated: true, completion: nil)
// HERE also tried pushViewController but that was also not working..
               self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

           }
```

Solution 2:-

Also tried self.navigationController?.viewController.removeAll() and then push/present the HomeView but that is also not working.

Anyone having any suggestion or tips to solve this.

Comment: This should do the job self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

Comment: @anishparajuli thanks for the tip but already tried this, its not working.

Answer (score 7):

A very fast way:

```
// Put this line in the UIViewController where you want to reset navigation
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [self]
```

You will erase the view controller stack and reset the navigation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use for it

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

or make some hack with navigation stack

```
var viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
let firstViewCtr = viewControllers?.first;
viewControllers?.removeAll()
viewControllers?.insert(firstViewCtr!, atIndex: 0)
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = viewControllers!
```

Comment: Bad luck but both are not working for me. Not sure about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reverting back the navigation, Why not you can set rootViewController for Window again like below?

```
SharedAppDelegate.window?.rootViewController = MainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeNavigationController")
```

Comment: I have updated the code as I am using pod for slider i think there it causing issue in redirecting, because i have created demo with 4 screen and on last screen i have put a button and on button click i just wrote 1 line - navigationController.popTorootviewcontroller(true) and it worked perfectly fine. Here I think as i have used pod its causing some issue. Please check the deleagate class and let me know if you can point out something there.

Answer (score 1):

For **Swift 3**, use the following code:

> self?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)